# Improve read speed of a virtual filesystem

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, mmap, sysfs

I am using sysfs to capture CPU information. These sysfs files allow us the ability to get a lot of kernel subsystem information in user space through virtual files. My question boils down to reading a large number of sysfs files, where overhead can become quite large. Some sample code:

```
int cpu0_freq_open() {
  int fd = open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
}

int cpu0_freq_read(int fd) {
  char buffer[64];
  if ( pread(fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1 ) {
    printf("Reading failed");
    return 1;
  }
  int freq = atoi(buffer);
  // function call to store the event value at this timestamp
}

int main() {
  int fd_cpu0 = cpu0_freq_open(); // we open for all cpu#s

  // do some action here
  // make a lot of cpu0_freq_read(fd_cpu0) calls for cpu0 and all other cpus

  cpu0_freq_close();
}
```

A single `pread()` call isn't too terrible, but if I make a calls to `cpu0_freq_read`, `cpu1_freq_read`, etc. then the overhead of all of these `pread()` calls add up quickly. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to retrieve the information from this virtual filesystem. The immediate alternative that comes to mind is memory mapping which won't work because we're dealing with a virtual filesystem. Are there ways to improve the read speed of these sysfs files? And, on a more broader scope, virtual filesystems in general?

Comment: Not really. When you read from a VFS, the kernel has to synthesize and format the results from kernel data structures. That's where all the overhead is, and there's not much you can do about it in the caller.

Comment: Barmar, think `select` or `epoll` might at least help parallelize the read process?  The kernel still has to keep up with all the reads, but maybe some of the latency can overlap

Comment: @erik258 I doubt you can use those operations on virtual files, they don't return data asynchronously.

Comment: @erik258 even if that worked, what events would you be polling for? Those are small virtual files consisting of a single line of text, doesn't make much sense to select/poll on them. It's not like you will ever have to wait for their content.

Comment: Absolutely not an answer, but you might want to check out [NETDATA](https://www.netdata.cloud/). It must surely be doing something very similar under the hood, and it's very lightweight. Open source, so you could look at how the code works.

Comment: Since you're using `pread` and seeking to 0, that is a _single_ syscall. I'd open the requisite files _once_ and store the file descriptors in an array. I modified/tested your program to do this (for 8 cpus) and it works fine.

Comment: Note that `pread()` does not `NUL`-terminate what it reads, and if `atoi()` gets data it can't interpret as an `int` you'll invoke undefined behavior.